# Non-defining relative clauses: use 'who' or 'which'

Tags: grammar

> We don't use 'that' in non-defining relative clauses, so we need to use 'which' if the pronoun refers to a thing, and 'who' if it refers to a person.

Is there any grammatical explanation why not to use 'that'?

Comment: Is that first bit a quote (missing attribution) or just offset to look pretty?

Comment: I like the red sports car, which goes fast. I like the red sports car which goes fast. If you said the two sentences aloud, could the listener tell you which sentence has the defining clause?  (written, you have the comma as a clue) But, I like the red sports car that goes fast. Which car do you like among the red sports cars? A reasonable convention.

Answer (score 6):

It's all the fault of one or both of the Fowler brothers!

This is what Geoff Pullum, co-author of CGEL, says:

"Let me tell you a little about Fowler and his 'rule', if I may. I think once you've read it you'll appreciate just why we really should ignore his advice.

Fowler has done a lot of damage. He invented a rule completely which has become the most famous rule for American copy editors (and in American schools it seems), though in the UK and elsewhere generally it's not nearly so well known. In fact, it doesn't really figure here at all in schools and colleges - most students have never even heard of the Fowler brothers, let alone their so-called 'rule'.

What happened was that the Fowlers noticed in 1906 that non-restrictive clauses were almost always, but not quite,  introduced by "which" if the head noun is non-human, and that they are hardly ever introduced by "that"; so there was almost a perfect line-up between being non-restrictive and beginning with "which". So they thought wouldn't it be neat, wouldn't it be good for English, to make it 100%, and at the same time make it a rule that restrictive relatives always begin with "that" and never with "which". And that's what happened. But that was never a rule that was characteristic of 18th/19th century English grammar. It's always been about 50/50 in texts - see the King James Bible quote in my other post - and later Roosevelt did not use "which" when referring to 7th December 1941 because he was ignorant of English grammar; he actually had a good command of grammar. (By the way, is he ridiculed for using "which?)

But the Fowlers' became so influential that people started rarifying their recommendations as though they were grammatical rules. Nuns started teaching the "which" rule in American schools and somehow it got from there to college courses, and copy editors started work believing they had to enforce it. And all for no good reason at all - just a silly rule with no foundation that satisfied the Fowlers' desire for syntactic tidiness. Those who believe it have simply been conned.
Though still in print, Fowler's 'Modern English Usage' is a dinosaur. Know about it, but tuck it away in a dark corner of your study, as I have."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137437/discussion-on-answer-by-billj-non-defining-relative-clauses-use-who-or-which).

Comment: @BillJ "Know about it, but tuck it away in a dark corner of your study, as I have." As an experiment, why don't you extract it from that dark corner, dust it off, and read Fowler's discussion of that as a relative pronoun. None of what you said in your answer is true to what Fowler wrote.  He was not a rule maker.

Comment: @Zan700 Do you have a copy of *The Kings English*? The 1906 edition? And which version of the other, subsequent publication are you quoting from?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have A Dictionary of Modern English Usage by H.W. Fowler, second edition, Oxford University Press, 1965, revised by Sir Ernest Gowers. The first edition was published in 1926. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. BTW, the passage is under "that, rel. pron." Page 625 in my book.

Comment: @billj Any chance of a citation (or link) for that quote?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. No, I'm afraid not. It's something that GKP said some years ago, but I don't recall exactly where.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I recall that last line very well, but can't remember where from.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use that, which or whatever strikes your fancy.

Here is H. W. Fowler's position. "What grammarians say should be has perhaps less influence on what shall be than even he more modest of them realize; *usage evolves itself little disturbed by their likes and dislikes* [my italics]. And yet the temptation to show how better use might have been made of the material at hand is sometimes irresistible. The English relatives, particularly as used by English rather than American writers, offer such a temptation. *The relations between that, who, and which have come to us from our forefathers as an odd jumble* [my italics], and plainly show that the language has not been neatly constructed by a master builder who could create each part to do the exact work required of it, neither overlapped, nor overlapping; far from it, its parts have had to grow as they could."